# How do I remove an item from a Set persisted with JDO?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo, datanucleus

I have a container object that contains of set of objects that is persisted in Google App Engine using [JDO 2.3](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/overview). I want to remove an object from the set contents. With the following test code, the remove() method returns false, but the change is not persisted, as the following code demonstrates. However, the set cardinality is reduced (this behavior astonishes me). How can I correct this sample to remove the specified object from the set (in this case, object "one")?

I haven't been able to find anything relevant in the JDO documentation. Equality checks and hashing are based on [this article](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html).

A dump of the console log with the log level turned up is [here](http://pastebin.com/Jumr0Jue) (update: this is transactionless version).

A dump of the console log with transactions is [here](http://pastebin.com/ym5kdftw).

**Container.java**

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.jdo.annotations.FetchGroup;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PersistenceCapable;
import javax.jdo.annotations.Persistent;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PrimaryKey;

@PersistenceCapable(detachable = "true")
@FetchGroup(name = "withContents", members = { @Persistent(name = "contents") })
public class Container
{
    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;

    @Persistent(dependentElement = "true")
    private Set<Containee> contents;

    public Set<Containee> getContents()
    {
        return contents;
    }

    public Container(String id)
    {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        contents = new HashSet<Containee>();
    }
}
```

**Containee.java**

```
import javax.jdo.annotations.Extension;
import javax.jdo.annotations.IdGeneratorStrategy;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PersistenceCapable;
import javax.jdo.annotations.Persistent;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PrimaryKey;

@PersistenceCapable(detachable = "true")
public class Containee
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    @Extension(vendorName = "datanucleus", 
       key = "gae.encoded-pk", value = "true")
    private String id;

    @Persistent
    private String friendlyName;

    public String getFriendlyName()
    {
        return friendlyName;
    }

    public Containee(String friendlyName)
    {
        this.friendlyName = friendlyName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other)
    {
        if (other instanceof Containee)
        {
            Containee that = (Containee) other;
            return this.getFriendlyName().equals(that.getFriendlyName());
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return friendlyName.hashCode();
    }
}
```

**Test snippet** (run server-side as part of a RemoteService)

```
...

        System.out.println("Fetching...");
        Container after = pm.getObjectById(Container.class, "test");

        // prints 2
        System.out.println("Pre-remove set cardinality "
                + after.getContents().size());

        // prints "true"
        System.out.println("Post-store containment: "
                + after.getContents().contains(one));

        for (Containee e : after.getContents())
        {
            System.out.println(e.getFriendlyName());
        }

        System.out.println("Mark");
        boolean result = after.getContents().remove(one);
        System.out.println("End Mark");

        System.out
                .println("'after' object class: " + after.getContents().getClass());

        // prints "false" (!?!?)
        System.out.println("Post-store removal: " + result);

        // prints 1 (...?)
        System.out.println("Post-remove set cardinality: "
                + after.getContents().size());

...
```

**Edit:**

**Test snippet with transactions**

```
    Container before = new Container("test");

    Containee one = new Containee("one");
    Containee two = new Containee("two");
    Containee three = new Containee("three");

    before.getContents().add(one);
    before.getContents().add(two);
    before.getContents().add(three);

    // prints "true"
    System.out.println("Pre-store containment: "
            + before.getContents().contains(two));

    // prints "true"
    System.out.println("Pre-store removal: "
            + before.getContents().remove(two));

    PersistenceManager pm = pmf.getPersistenceManager();

    try
    {
        pm.makePersistent(before);
    }
    finally
    {
        pm.close();
    }

    pm = pmf.getPersistenceManager();
    pm.getFetchPlan().addGroup("withContents");

    Transaction tx = pm.currentTransaction();

    try
    {
        System.out.println("Fetching...");
        Container after = pm.getObjectById(Container.class, "test");

        // prints 2
        System.out.println("Pre-remove set cardinality "
                + after.getContents().size());

        // prints "true"
        System.out.println("Post-store containment: "
                + after.getContents().contains(one));

        for (Containee e : after.getContents())
        {
            System.out.println(e.getFriendlyName());
        }

        tx.begin();

        System.out.println("Mark");
        boolean hrm = after.getContents().remove(one);
        System.out.println("End Mark");

        tx.commit();

        System.out
                .println("'after' object class: " + after.getContents().getClass());

        // prints "false" (!?!?)
        System.out.println("Post-store removal: " + hrm);

        // prints 1 (...?)
        System.out.println("Post-remove set cardinality: "
                + after.getContents().size());

    }
    finally
    {
        System.out.println("Finalizing transaction...");
        if (tx.isActive())
        {
            System.out.println("Rolling back...");
            tx.rollback();
        }
    }

    pm.close();

    pm = pmf.getPersistenceManager();
    pm.getFetchPlan().addGroup("withContents");

    try
    {
        System.out.println("Fetching again...");
        Container after = pm.getObjectById(Container.class, "test");

        // prints 2
        System.out.println("Final set cardinality "
                + after.getContents().size());
    }
    finally
    {
        pm.close();
    }
```

Comment: What state is "after" when you call remove? and the collection is of what type ? a wrapper type ? or java.util.HashSet? and then what goes in the log when you call remove? (put a print in just before remove call, and one just after). And then repeat the operation but within a transaction ... since semantics of updates are different when nontransactional

Comment: @DataNucleus I've updated the question to answer your questions--the states are listed in the log file, and the collection type is `org.datanucleus.sco.backed.Set`. The transactional version and log are also listed--the output appears to be the same.

Comment: I've been able to reduce this to a simpler test case: the collection is unnecessary, any property of a non-primitive type exhibits the same behavior. What are peoples' thoughts on posting a new question vs. rewrite the original?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a weekend of head scratching and frustration, I've found a work-around: leverage *reference* equality instead of *value* equality when calling Set.remove(). Here's the code (interesting bit starts at the comment "get a reference to the object in the persisted Set"):

```
    Container before = new Container("test");

    Containee one = new Containee("one");
    Containee two = new Containee("two");
    Containee three = new Containee("three");

    before.getContents().add(one);
    before.getContents().add(two);
    before.getContents().add(three);

    pm = pmf.getPersistenceManager();

    try
    {
        pm.makePersistent(before);
    }
    finally
    {
        pm.close();
    }

    pm = pmf.getPersistenceManager();

    try
    {
        Container after = pm.getObjectById(Container.class, "test");

        // prints 3
        System.out.println("Pre-remove set cardinality "
                + after.getContents().size());

        // prints "true"
        System.out.println("Post-store containment: "
                + after.getContents().contains(one));

        //get a reference to the object in the persisted Set
        //that is value-equivalent to Containee #1
        Containee ref = null;
        for (Containee c : after.getContents())
        {
            if (c.equals(one)) ref = c;
        }

        if (ref != null)
        {
            after.getContents().remove(ref);
        }

        // prints 2
        System.out.println("Post-remove set cardinality: "
                + after.getContents().size());

    }
    finally
    {
        pm.close();
    }

    pm = pmf.getPersistenceManager();

    try
    {
        Container after = pm.getObjectById(Container.class, "test");

        // prints 2 (as expected)
        System.out.println("Final set cardinality "
                + after.getContents().size());
    }
    finally
    {
        pm.close();
    }
```

This code doesn't show it, but wrapping the operation with a pessimistic transaction is probably a good plan, to avoid concurrency issues.

The success of this technique leads me to suspect that the DataNucleus framework uses object references instead of equality checks to handle deletions, but I haven't found anything in the documentation that confirms or disproves that hypothesis.

Comment: Stil seems to be the case as of datanucleus-appengine 2.1.2, thanks you saved me 75% of a weekend's headscratching!

Answer (score 1):

Your Relationship is not done correctly.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/relationships#Owned_One_to_Many_Relationships

Container.java

```
// ...
@Persistent(mappedBy = "employee", dependentElement = "true")
private Set<Containee> contents;
```

Containee.java

```
// ...
@Persistent
private Container container;
```

Comment: If the relation is UNIDIRECTIONAL then it does not need a link back to the Container

Comment: does it work with JDO 2.3? Wouldn't he need to use Set<Key> instead of Set<Containee>? see this link [unowend](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/relationships#Unowned_Relationships)

Comment: JDO is not the question (since it allows specification of uni and bi directional relations), what you mean is does GAE plugin v1.x work ok like that. Certainly using v2 of the GAE plugin there is no reason to have any back link, and I'd be surprised of v1.x needed one too. Set<Key> would only be needed for simulating unowned relations, and the user doesn't state that he needs that